# Can I tune this query to get rid of fn:distinct-values?

Tags: marklogic

Can anyone tell me if I can improve this query by getting rid of the `fn:distinct-values($d2)` expression?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace zespc = "http://www.cendris.nl/postcode";
declare namespace op = "http://www.nvsp.nl/oplage-mapping";

let $wijk := '665402'
let $d1 := fn:distinct-values(fn:doc('/data/map/oplage-mapping.xml')//op:map[@wijk_id = $wijk]/@ppc6_id)

let $q1 := cts:element-attribute-range-query(
      xs:QName("op:map"), xs:QName("wijk_id"), "=",
      $wijk)

let $d2 := cts:search(//op:map,$q1)/@ppc6_id
let $d3 := fn:distinct-values($d2)

return (fn:count($d1), fn:count($d3))
```

Thx,

hugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what your goal is, but this should return equivalent results. You will need another attribute range index, this time on `op:map/@ppc6_id`.

Watch out for collations, and consider using numeric types if that's appropriate.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace zespc="http://www.cendris.nl/postcode";
declare namespace op="http://www.nvsp.nl/oplage-mapping";

let $wijk := '665402' (: Consider using integers instead of strings :)
let $q-wijk := cts:element-attribute-range-query(
  xs:QName("op:map"), xs:QName("wijk_id"),
  '=', $wijk)
let $ref-ppc := cts:element-attribute-reference(
    xs:QName('op:map'), xs:QName('ppc6_id'))
let $values-doc := cts:values(
  $ref-ppc, (),
  cts:and-query(
    (cts:document-query('/data/map/oplage-mapping.xml'),
     $q-wijk)))
let $values-all := cts:values($ref-ppc, (), $q-wijk)
return (count($values-doc), count($values-all))
```

Comment: my goal is to increase speed, in need this query as part of an aggregation function aggregating roughly 500.000 docs to around 40.000 documents. Profiling what i have so far seems that all is now in the same order of magnitude so this whas to do. I have not checked your answer but will accept it. thx

Comment: I meant "goal" at a higher level, something like a user story. With a big aggregation problem you should look at http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-co-occurrences and the `map` option. That way one database request returns a giant map with all of your aggregation data in it. Possibly this is even a case for some C++: http://docs.marklogic.com/cpp/udf/index.html